# Position 4 JPanel in a JFrame in this way

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

How can I position 4 JPanel like the img below

[image]

```
public class Main {

    static JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[]args){
            frame = new JFrame("TPTPRG");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           // frame.setResizable(false);
            //Add content to the window.
            frame.add(new JPanelNumber1(), BorderLayout.?????);
            frame.add(new JPanelNumber2(), BorderLayout.?????);
            frame.add(new JPanelNumber3(), BorderLayout.?????);
            frame.add(new JPanelNumber4(), BorderLayout.?????);


            //frame.setUndecorated(true);

            //frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 255, 0, 0));
            //new FullScreen().setFullScreen(frame); // full screen JFrame, works
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Or is better if I add the 4 JPanel in a JPanel_Main ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
frame.add(new JPanelNumber1(), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
frame.add(new JPanelNumber2(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
frame.add(new JPanelNumber3(), BorderLayout.LINE_END);
frame.add(new JPanelNumber4(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: @peeskillet  Good question.  I am presuming that by 'dispose' the OP meant 'lay out', but it could do with clarification.

Comment: Andrew Thompson , you are right , sorry but "to dispose" in my language it sounded correct ,